# Why is my player model immediately teleporting above the ground the moment I move it forward?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Right when I hit 'w' to move the character forward it teleports above ground. I'm not using a Character Controller. I'm guessing it has something to do with the player being grounded. I'm very very new to all of this and any help would be really appreciated. Thank you

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController   : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CharacterController controller;
    private Vector3 playerVelocity;
    private bool groundedPlayer;
    private float playerSpeed = 4.0f;
    private float jumpHeight = 1.0f;
    private float gravityValue = -9.81f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        controller = gameObject.AddComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        groundedPlayer = controller.isGrounded;
        if (groundedPlayer && playerVelocity.y < 0 )
        {
            playerVelocity.y = 0f;
        }

        Vector3 move = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);

        if (move != Vector3.zero)
        {
            gameObject.transform.forward = move;
        }

        //Changes the height position of the player..
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && groundedPlayer)
            {
            playerVelocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -3.0f * gravityValue);
        }

        playerVelocity.y += gravityValue * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't want to set the transform.forward vector. You only want to read its value.
`gameObject.transform.forward = move;`

Comment: Setting `transform.forward` to rotate the character's facing direction is fine. However, this is a direction vector so you want to normalize move after creating it: `move.Normalize()`.

Comment: @DerChef wouldn't matter .. Unity will normalize it anyway the moment you assign it to `transform.forward` ;) But yes for the `controller.Move` it would matter

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of potenial errors in your code. However, it is hard to determine the source of your problem with the given information. Could you please provide screenshots of the scene and your character's inspector?

First off, you wrote

> I'm not using a Character Controller.

despite clearly using a CharacterController. I'm guessing this is a typo.
Please make sure, that the collider of your CharacterController and your ground colliders are properly configured. This is the likeliest source of the problem.

Concerning your script: You're applying `gravityValue` even if you're already grounded and you're multiplying `Time.deltaTime` twice.

EDIT: Taking a look at this again, I see that you add your CharacterController at runtime using `AddComponent`. This makes it even more likely, that the problem exists, because your CharacterController's collider is not properly configured. Just add the CharacterController to your character via the inspector, configure it, then use a serialized reference in your script which you can assign in the inspector. Like this:

```
[SerializeField] private CharacterController controller;
```

You could also simply use `GetComponent` instead of `AddComponent` if you don't want to serialize the CharacterController for some reason.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Your advice worked out.